# implement InterVlan Routing in campus network

Tags: networking, routes, cisco

Good day to all!

I have a task to compare different approaches to **implement InterVLAN routing** in campus network. Google suggests only Cisco technologies for such query. But what I need is also other companies solutions (like Dell, HP), cost of the implementations, pros and cons etc. Also some kind of article discribing a general overview of the problem would be useful.
Any help is appreciated! Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the companies you mentioned have solutions available to you.  "Intervlan routing" is the only requirement you've listed.  All enterprise network equipment vendors deliver this feature.  So you don't need to consider it a requirement, I'd say - you're going to get that from anyone.  You should discuss this with a networking reseller/consultant so they can discover your true requirements (like power over ethernet for IP phones, etc) and hopefully you can work together to design a solution that meets your requirements and budget constraints.